# Magento module layout xml file not working

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9, I have created a module and also declared financing.xml file in config.xml file.
But this financing.xml file is not calling. Actually i have written script to remove JS file. But it is not working.

```
   <frontend>    
      <layout>
        <updates>
            <icebox_financing>
                <file>financing.xml</file>
            </icebox_financing>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

financing.xml file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <financing_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js</name></action>
        </reference>         
    </financing_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

where have you placed this financing.xml file?

```
<file>your_module/financing.xml</file>
```

should be placed in

```
app/design/base/default/layout/your_module/financing.xml
```

or

app/design/your_package/your_theme_defaut/layout/your_module/financing.xml

Comment: Hello Martin, Yes financing.xml file is placed on app/design/your_package/your_theme_defaut/layout/your_module/financing.xml

Comment: Is there have any way to check my xml file is calling or not ? Thank you

Comment: Have you cleared cache or removed cache forders from var? 
xml files are being merged and cached

Comment: Yes Martin, i cleared Cache folder, but no luck

Comment: Is your xml defining any block? could you paste the xml content?

Comment: Yes i updated my post, there you can see my financing.xml file

Comment: Anybody can tell me that how can i check that xml file is working or not ?

Comment: Do you have the load layout code in the controller indexAction? Are you sure that js file is in js folder? if it is in skin folder you should use 
    <type>skin_js</type>

Comment: You could check if your xml is being loaded by debbuging the 
$this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout();
        $this->renderLayout(); in your controller action

Comment: My this remove script work fine if i use it in CMS page layout section. But now i want it by layout xml file.   Here is my indexAction code-   $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
        $block->setTemplate('page/finance_form.phtml');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->renderLayout();

Comment: anybody have got issue like this  ? Thank you